# Normed Linear Space ,$p \neq 2$ is $\left \| f\right \|_{p}= \sqrt{f,f}$ for each $ f \in L^P([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For $p \neq 2$, is there an inner product $< ., .>$ on $L^P([0,1])$ such that $\left \| f\right \|_{p}= \sqrt{f,f}$ for each $ f \in L^P([0,1])$?

is it true?for P=2 norm is induced by inner product which is not Euclidean.if its true how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take a look at the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if a norm is derived from an inner product in that way, then the inner product is uniquely determined by the norm and there is an explicit algebraic expression for (f,g) in terms of ||f||, ||g||, ||f+g|| and ||f-g||.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the norm were induced by an inner product it would satisfy the parallelogram law $$||f+g||^2+||f-g||^2=2(||f||^2+||g||^2).$$Simple examples show this is not so (for example, the characteristic functions of two disjoint sets).

Comment: Thank you so much!im having trouble to construct a counterexample .can you help me constructing such an example?im from other discipline so having a lot of trouble in this course.thanks

Comment: I told you how to get a counterexample! Consider the characterisitc functions of two disjoint sets

Comment: i tried with $f=\chi_[0,1/2)$ and
$g=\chi_[1/2,1)$  but parallelogram law seems to hold.im really sorry.i have real trouble understanding charectaristics function

Comment: Well you're doing something wrong in the calculations then.